# Chrome - background attachment fixed flickers

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, parallax

We have this page - [Cloud it](http://www.cloud-it.sk/) and there is apparently a css problem or some interference in the slider section. The background of slider container has a background-attachment: fixed and background-size: cover property to maintain the parallax-like effect.
In chrome (Version 28.0.1500.71) we see a huge flickering and jumping of the whole background image.

We have not yet found any solution to this problem. Is there anyone who has met this problem before, or someone who can give us a good advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#wrapper-presentation {
  /* z-index: 101; */
}
```

This fixes your jumping background and shows the green side tab as well.

To also hide the green tab and show it when the user scrolls down, do this (jQuery):

```
.trigger {display: none;}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollHt = 600;

    if($(this).scrollTop() >= scrollHt) {
        $('.trigger').stop().fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.trigger').stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, do you think there is a solution how to hide green tab underneath and still get rid of these flickerings?

Comment: Help me understand why you'd want to do that and I'll take another look.

Comment: The content in sliding out tab is the same form that is placed in the slider wrapper. So it's ideal when it's available only on scroll down (speaking of home page). Thanks.